# Wordpress pages randomly serve as RSS/XML content

Tags: apache, wordpress, rss

For months we have been struggling with a weird issue on 1 of our Wordpress Network installations. We have 4 installations on 1 VPS and only one of the four installations generates this error.

The problem is that pages on all sites that run on that Wordpress Network installation, randomly(?) seem to try and parse the page as being RSS content. See this screenshot: [image]
[*Full image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lYLU.jpg)

This only happens once per session (if it does at all) and after refreshing the page, all is good. This makes it extremely hard to fix, because debugging is almost impossible.

Whenever the issue seems to appear, the (RSS) content that is being displayed, is that of a different page..

Could this be a Wordpress issue, or could this be an issue in the Apache config?

Some domains we are encountering this on:

- [http://www.skynetsg.co.za/](http://www.skynetsg.co.za/contact-us/test-3/)
- http://www.workplacestrategies.co.za/
- http://www.beachbreaks.co.za/

I hope there is someone that could help me solve this issue!

**Update**:
I just had the issue on the page: http://www.skynetsg.co.za/peter-sserwanga/ that was newly created. I checked the apache logs and they show nothing strange, just a 200 OK header..

Comment: does the problem also exist if you turn permalinks off?

Comment: Hi Jan, I wouldn't know how to test this.. Do you perhaps have an idea? 99.9% the site just works fine, but if I turn off the permalinks, everything will work fine of course...

Comment: in the wp-admin -> settings-> permalinks. And there default/standard which looks like: url.com/?p=123

Comment: @janw, I know how to change the settings. But the problem is that I only sporadically get the problem: "This only happens once per session (if it does at all) and after refreshing the page, all is good. This makes it extremely hard to fix, because debugging is almost impossible.". Thats what makes it hard to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a link that may fix your problem. If your running WHM/Cpanel, you may have to recompile apache with out certain modules.

[rss-feed-displayed-instead-of-html-page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rss-feed-displayed-instead-of-html-page?replies=4)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tomorrow and let you know what I can find.

Comment: The answer provided in that link does not apply to my issue, I checked the caching solution and all works fine. It has however set me in another direction and made some other changes that might have fixed the issue. I will see what happens and post back when I have news. Thanks.

Comment: I look forward to see your results and hope you fix the problem.